# How to delete particular value from XML node instead of full node in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have an xml field in my table : XmlDoc which has various tags.. but I need to delete a particular value from a tag rather than deleting whole tag itself.

I have already tried using

```
update table
set XmlDoc.modify('delete //DeliveryMechanism//Address//text()[contains("abc@gmail.com")]')
```

but it deletes all the value from the tag but I need to remove only abc@gmail.com"

```
<DeliveryMechanism>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Email</Name>
    <Description />
    <IsActive>false</IsActive>
    <Address>def@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com,hij@gmail.com</Address>
    <DeliveryOptions xmlns:p3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      p3:type="DeliveryOptionsEmail">
        <MailPriority>Normal</MailPriority>
    </DeliveryOptions>
</DeliveryMechanism>
```

I need tag to be like

```
<Address>def@gmail.com,hij@gmail.com</Address>
```

Comment: Is this for SQL Server? Or another RDBMS perhaps?

Comment: This is for SQL

Comment: I mean the product you are working on. SQL is ANSI-SQL, but not one commercial product implements ANSI-SQL. Each product implements its own dialect of SQL. You can read the SQL tag by hovering over it with your mouse: the text explicitly asks to include a tag for the RDBMS product you are working.

Comment: From the sample code using `.modify()` I'm pretty sure this is SQL-Server...

Comment: @Himsy I changed the tags of your question the way I think it fits better. Please feel free to change them back, if this is not correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not as simple as you might think...

The problem is: You should **never ever** store your data as a delimited string. Instead of the comma-separated list of email addresses, you should rather use a list of nested nodes. But sometimes we have to stick with bad design. This is a way to solve this:

A mockup-scenario with three test cases:

```
DECLARE @mockTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, Descr VARCHAR(100), yourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @mockTable VALUES
('Your sample'
,'<DeliveryMechanism>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Email</Name>
    <Description />
    <IsActive>false</IsActive>
    <Address>def@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com,hij@gmail.com</Address>
    <DeliveryOptions xmlns:p3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      p3:type="DeliveryOptionsEmail">
        <MailPriority>Normal</MailPriority>
    </DeliveryOptions>
</DeliveryMechanism>') 
,('Your sample without the given mail address'
,'<DeliveryMechanism>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Email</Name>
    <Description />
    <IsActive>false</IsActive>
    <Address>def@gmail.com,hij@gmail.com;oneMore@test.com</Address>
    <DeliveryOptions xmlns:p3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      p3:type="DeliveryOptionsEmail">
        <MailPriority>Normal</MailPriority>
    </DeliveryOptions>
</DeliveryMechanism>') 
,('Your sample with twice the given mail address'
,'<DeliveryMechanism>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Email</Name>
    <Description />
    <IsActive>false</IsActive>
    <Address>abc@gmail.com,hij@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com</Address>
    <DeliveryOptions xmlns:p3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      p3:type="DeliveryOptionsEmail">
        <MailPriority>Normal</MailPriority>
    </DeliveryOptions>
</DeliveryMechanism>');
```

--a variable to set the email we want to find and delete

```
DECLARE @givenAddress VARCHAR(100)='abc@gmail.com';
```

--the query

```
WITH PreComputation AS
(
    SELECT t.*
          ,STUFF(
           CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t.yourXml.value('(/DeliveryMechanism/Address/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
                .query('for $a in /x[text()[1] != sql:variable("@givenAddress")]/text()
                        return
                        <x>{concat(",",$a)}</x>').value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') theNewList
    FROM @mockTable t
    WHERE t.yourXml.exist('/DeliveryMechanism[Address[contains(text()[1],sql:variable("@givenAddress"))]]')=1
) 
UPDATE PreComputation SET yourXml.modify('replace value of (/DeliveryMechanism/Address/text())[1] with sql:column("theNewList")');
```

--Check the result

```
SELECT * FROM @mockTable;
```

The idea in short:

The CTE `PreComputation` will first use `.exist()` to reduce the work onto rows which contain the sepcific address.
The next step is to use some string manipulations, to transform your CSV-list to XML and cast it to a native XML.
Once having a native XML we can use `XQuery`
The `.query()` will return all email fragments, where the `text()` is **not equal** to the given address.
Some tricks with `concat()` ,`.value()` and `STUFF()` later, we now have the newly created CSV-list without the given address.
The final `UPDATE` can use this with `sql:column()`.

Good luck ;-)